# How does one pass AJAX vars from jQuery to their controller?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have an email form. But I'm making a test email form where a user can add a unique email, and have the email test send it to that particular email.

To make it easy, I decided to make the test email perform via ajax, and stick the whole thing inside of the other email form.

**I can't figure out how to send the variables from my HAML to my controller**

**new.html.haml**

```
- form_tag admin_email_blast_path do
  Subject
  %br
  = text_field_tag 'subject', :class => "mass_email_subject"
  %br
  Body
  %br
  = text_area_tag 'message', '', :name => 'editor1', :class => "mass_email_body"
  %br/
  = submit_tag 'Send Email', :class => 'button'

  .grid_3.right.align_right.suffix_1  # <= TEST EMAIL :D
    = text_field_tag 'email', nil, :style => "width: 150px;", :class => "test_email_address"
    = link_to 'Test Email',  test_email_admin_email_blast_path, :class => 'button test_email'
```

**JS**

```
$(".test_email").live("click", function() {

  var email = $(".test_email_address")
  var subject = $(".mass_email_subject");
  var body = $(".mass_email_body");

  data = "email=" + email.val() + "&subject" + subject.val() + "&body" + body.val();

  $.ajax({type: "GET", 
          url: $(this).attr("href"), 
          dataType: "script"
          data: data
          });
  return false;
});
```

**Controller**

```
def test_email
  debugger
  email = params[:email]
  subject = params[:subject]
  body = params[:body]
  Notifier.deliver_email_blast(email, subject, body)
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
admin.resource :email_blast, :member => {
                                :test_email => :get
                                }
```

I apologize ahead of time if this is a dumb newbie question. :(

Comment: Does test_email_admin_email_blast_path accept GET requests? (Try "rake routes | grep test_email_admin_email_blast" to see how Rails interprets your routes.rb)

Comment: Yes. test_email_admin_email_blast GET    /admin/email_blast/test_email(.:format)                                                                {:controller=>"admin/email_blasts", :action=>"test_email"}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `data` parameter:

```
$('.test_email').live('click', function() {

    var subject = $('.mass_email_subject');
    var body = $('.mass_email_body');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: this.href, 
        dataType: 'script',
        data: { subject: subject.val(), body: body.val() }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes but how does that connect to my rails controller? How do I set the vars for my Notifier?

Comment: All this does is it sends an AJAX request to `/testemail/?subject=foo&body=bar` and executes the returned javascript from this controller action.

Comment: Right. I got that part down. But it doesn't answer my question how these variables can be read by the rails controller. I appreciate the help nonetheless.

Comment: It's giving me a 'doesn't know what those vars are' error. I assume I have to set them such as `email = foobar` . But how do I set it to something that's geting passed to it?

Comment: The js var is `email`, and I'm trying to send `email` as a var in the controller with `Notifier.deliver_email_blast(email, subject, body)` . Without saying the var, it says it doesn't know what `email`, etc. is. When I set `email = email` . It says I have a `nil object when i didn't expect it`. Any ideas?

Comment: They'll be in `params`, so `subject = params[:subject]`, just like normal requests to rails.

Comment: Ah thanks @thenduks. Well, unfortunately it looks like those vars posted by @Darin don't pass through. Perhaps because its a "GET" and not a "POST" ?

Comment: Seems to me that'd be because he's got the `var subject = ...` line wrong, missing `.val()` :) No reason it shouldn't allow get... well, it would depend on your routes... Really you should just go ahead and make it a post, since that's what you're doing -- posting.

Comment: So I changed both the AJAX request, and the Routes.rb to Post and I get `Only post requests are allowed.` . Whatever the heck that means :D

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are getting the submit to work correctly based on Darin Dimitrov answer then you need to use the params object. In this case it looks like all you need to do is access params[:subject] and params[:body] in your controller action.

EDIT:

In response to the comment, GET and POST make no difference to params. If the form is not working, try modifying you JS to use serialize and return an error on failure:

```
$(".test_email").live("click", function() {

  var subject = $(".mass_email_subject")
  var body = $(".mass_email_body")

  $.ajax({type: "GET", 
          url: $(this).attr("href"), 
          dataType: "script"
          data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
          error: function(){ alert("There was a problem, please try again.") }
          });
  return false;
});
```

If it still is not working then you better look to see if your controller action is being hit at all.

Comment: The form below doesn't work. The vars don't pass to params[:subject], or any of the others. Is that because its a "GET" and not a "POST"? I tried both, also making sure that my route member is a :post request. When the routes.rb request and the ajax request is POST, then I get a `Only post requests are allowed`. when they are both GET, I get a nil param.

Comment: The controller is getting hit. I put a debugger right before when i define the params. But once I get there, they are all defined to `nil`. Strange right? I tried your serialize() method, and put a unique id around my form, and it doesn't give.

Comment: Where exactly is your debugger...after `def test_email` ?

Comment: It's right before the vars. Right after `def test_email` right before `user = params[:email]`

Comment: Could this have anything to do with my DTD? Or do I need this line anywhere ? `'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}`  . I noticed that in a RAilscast

Comment: That request header trick doesn't matter for actually seeing the params (it's to ensure that Rails knows the request is javascript, not html).

Comment: Look into changing that link_to into a link_to_function or button_to_function so it calls the JS more directly.  Little bit of a guess at this point

Comment: in your debugger, you can also take a glance at `controller.request.headers` and browse through that, especially REQUEST_URI, to see if the data is at least encoded. The params should definitely show up. What app server are you running when you see those results?

Comment: Wow! I got it! And I also realized I am retarded. After all is said and done, i didn't have my .js included.. can we just keep this between you guys and me? :)